# How to display the payment methods immediately below the checkout button

Tags: magento2.2

[image: Express Checkout]

Plz help me out to implement this. I have developed a custom Payment Methods for Magento 2.2.5. I need to display a express checkout option immediately below the checkout button in shopping cart (Screenshot attached). Is there any way to implement it??

Comment: Can Someone help me...!